# Is it possible to put in a resource dictionary a Transform3DGroup with binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, 3d, transform

I'm trying to create a 3d scene to represent graphically my model.
My model contains N objects (objA, objB, ...) each of them derive from an abstract class that has some property like Position,With,Height,Length etc

At the moment my Viewport3D is done in this way:

```
<Viewport3D>
    ...
    <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource objAView}">
        <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <Transform3DGroup>
                <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding Path=objA.Width}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=objA.Height}" ScaleZ="{Binding Path=objA.Length}"/>
                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="{Binding Path=objA.Position.X}" OffsetY="{Binding Path=objA.Position.Y}" OffsetZ="{Binding Path=objA.Position.Z}"/>
            </Transform3DGroup>
        </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource objBView}">
        <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <Transform3DGroup>
                <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="{Binding Path=objB.Width}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=objB.Height}" ScaleZ="{Binding Path=objB.Length}"/>
                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="{Binding Path=objB.Position.X}" OffsetY="{Binding Path=objB.Position.Y}" OffsetZ="{Binding Path=objB.Position.Z}"/>
            </Transform3DGroup>
        </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    ...
</Viewport3D>
```

Is it possible to avoid to rewrite the Transform3DGroup for each ModelVisual3D giving that they are almost the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a way to do it with resources the way your title suggests, because you'd only be able to specify the binding once.

However, you could write a class that derives from `Transform3DGroup` and takes a single binding of whatever the objA and obB are. So you could have something like this in your code instead:

```
<Viewport3D>
    ...
    <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource objAView}">
        <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <custom:MyTransform3DGroup ObjectToBindAgainst="{Binding objA}" />
        </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D Content="{StaticResource objBView}">
        <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <custom:MyTransform3DGroup ObjectToBindAgainst="{Binding objB}" />
        </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
    </ModelVisual3D>
    ...
</Viewport3D>
```

And then in your custom class you can use the ObjectToBindAgainst to set all the other pieces of the included transforms.

It doesn't save you a whole lot if you're really just doing this twice, but if you're doing it many times, it might be worth it.

Comment: Is not possible to derive from a sealed class as Transform3DGroup is